# Malloc error when trying to run node js server due to ibm_db module

Tags: c++, node.js, macos, npm, malloc

I have a nodejs application, and configured to run on port 5001. When I try to run the node server using *node server.js*, it throws me an malloc error like below

```
node(6080,0x1067aa600) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffb503d2670: pointer being freed was not allocated
node(6080,0x1067aa600) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      node server.js
```

My machine configs are
Processor - 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory - 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

When I try to run this server, I do not run any other node server. I also checked all the processes running but nothing clashes with it. Maybe I am missing something. I tried running it on different ports as well, but i get the same error

My node js version is v14.16.1

npm version is 6.14.12

Xcode version is 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267

Comment: What is your IDE? There might be an issue with XCode.

Also, what is your application that you are trying to run? Can you give more context?

Comment: I am running a node application. My IDE at the moment is vscode. But this even happen if I run the node application from terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not related with X code or node version but it was related to one the npm package I was using which was ibm_db and only if you have the mac monterey os.

Follow these step if you have this package installed to rectify the error.

1. Delete ibm_db package from your project and delete package-lock.json as well.
2. Install latest ibm_db package currently 2.8.1. Even if it does not resolve the error, do the last step.
3. Go to node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver/lib and rename the file *libstdc++.6.dylib* to anything like *libstdc++.7.dylib*

You can find detailed discussion here
https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/824
https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/801

Hopefully the issue will be resolved. Thanks